# How to Find similarity in structured data using rapidminer?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, similarity, rapidminer

I want to find the similarity using cosine similarity operator on the structured dataset but I am not getting the desired result. Can someone guide me how to find the similarity using the Rapidminer?

**Sample dataset:**

[image: Sample dataset]